# Is it possible to stop Pythons request library from url encoding post data?

Tags: python, python-requests

The entire question is in the title here:

Is it possible to stop Pythons request library from url encoding post data?

Comment: post a code snippet. `requests` does not url encode the payload of a POST

Comment: How are you doing the post? `data={"foo":"bar"}` will be sent with "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"